# I have a question about deepspeed's multi-GPU inference

Tags: pytorch, multi-gpu

In the inference tutorial: [Getting Started with DeepSpeed for Inferencing Transformer-based Models - DeepSpeed](https://www.deepspeed.ai/tutorials/inference-tutorial/), I am following along this example:

```
# Filename: gpt-neo-2.7b-generation.py
import os
import deepspeed
import torch
from transformers import pipeline

local_rank = int(os.getenv('LOCAL_RANK', '0'))
world_size = int(os.getenv('WORLD_SIZE', '1'))
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='EleutherAI/gpt-neo-2.7B',
                     device=local_rank)



generator.model = deepspeed.init_inference(generator.model,
                                           mp_size=world_size,
                                           dtype=torch.float,
                                           replace_with_kernel_inject=True)

string = generator("DeepSpeed is", do_sample=True, min_length=50)
if not torch.distributed.is_initialized() or torch.distributed.get_rank() == 0:
    print(string)
```

I would like to know:

1. When calling:

   ```
   deepspeed --num_gpus 2 gpt-neo-2.7b-generation.py
   ```

   Is the "generator" statement running once or twice?
2. If I should do something differently when having a different rank.